# Ajax Post in Zend Framework

Tags: ajax, post, zend-framework

I'm very very new in Zend Framework.
I wanted delete a row in db via $.post in jQuery that was not done.
I also did a lot of research on Google and Youtube, but I did not get result, Unfortunately.
Please help me.
ZF version: 1.11.2

application/Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initDb(){
$con=array('host'=>'127.0.0.1','username'=>'root','password'=>'','dbname'=>'sample_db');
    $db=Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql',$con);$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    Zend_Registry::set('db',$db);
}
```

application/controllers/DashboardController.php:

```
public function indexAction(){
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('a');
}
```

application/views/scripts/dashboard/index.phtml:

```
<a href="javascript:deleteTest('62989c12369ea3c1')">DELETE</a>
```

public/js/0.js:

```
function deleteTest(id){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
        $.post('http://127.0.0.1/Sample4/application/models/Guestdb.php',{funcName:'Delete_Test',id:id},function(r){alert(r)})
}
```

application/models/Guestdb.php:

```
class Model_Guestdb{
    public function Delete_Test(){
    $db=Zend_Registry::get('db');
        $r=$db->query("DELETE FROM `prac` WHERE `id`='".trim((new Zend_Filter_Decrypt(array('adapter'=>'mcrypt','key'=>'thisisakeytolock','vector'=>'myvector')))->filter(hex2bin($this->getRequest()->getPost()['id'])))."'");
        echo$r?'t':'f';
    }
}
$a=new Model_Guestdb();
if(isset($_POST['funcName']))call_user_func(array($a,$_POST['funcName']));
elseif(isset($_GET['funcName']))call_user_func(array($a,$_GET['funcName']));
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend_Registry' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sample4\application\models\Guestdb.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sample4\application\models\Guestdb.php(35): Model_Guestdb->Delete_Test() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sample4\application\models\Guestdb.php on line 6
```

Sorry for my english
Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Class 'Zend_Registry' not found" do you have Zend_Registry in your project? Also if you are new in zf don't work on zf1. it's eol is passed already. just use zf3.

Comment: @Mehmet SÖĞÜNMEZ As you see i use Zend_Registry in Bootstrap.php and there is no problem.
The problem is either related to my Ajax or related to Guestdb.

Comment: The problem is: You are making a request to your model directly: "$.post('http://127.0.0.1/Sample4/application/models/Guestdb.php'" without using the routing, a controller-action, no bootstraping. Look at your public/index.php, then find your controller files(eg DefaultController.php or IndexController.php)& the actions defined inside these(eg indexAction()). Add the location of these files and maybe we can help you getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows:

application/views/scripts/dashboard/index.phtml:

```
<a href="javascript:del('210')">DELETE</a>
```

public/js/0.js:

```
function del(id){
    if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
        $.post('ajax',{func:'del',table:'prac',id:id},
            function(r){r=='t'?location.reload():alert('Error!')})
}
```

application/controllers/DashboardController.php:

```
<?php
class DashboardController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function ajaxAction(){
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $ajax=$this->getRequest()->getPost();$func=$ajax['func'];
        (new Model_Guestdb)->$func($ajax['table'],$ajax['id']);
    }
}
```

application/models/Guestdb.php:

```
class Model_Guestdb{
    public function del($table,$id){
        echo Zend_Registry::get('db')->query
        ("DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE `id`='$id'")?'t':'f';
    }
}
```

Thanks for friends comments.